# How to Make Outlook Email Filtering More Efficient (VBA)

Tags: vba, sorting, outlook, filtering

Sorry for the long post, I'm still a self taught amateur: but my project is to automate some tasks during which I can filter outlook mails potentially by Sender, and subject, and send them to specific folders. (For certain reasons I can't use the built in Outlook filter). The code below works fine, but some of the boxes the macro accesses are located on a server in another country, so some of the actions take a long time. Essentially, my code loops through a list of email addresses to filter out, and potential subject lines. It goes through every single email, compares sender name and subject, then determines which folder to send it to, and moves it.

My question is how can I make this more efficient, by either using more clever code, or reducing total number of actions? Is there a more efficient way to search through all of the emails rather than 1 by 1? Instead of moving 1 by 1, is it possible to move them all in blocks? I'd be so appreciative if someone could help. My code is below (I realize there are some unneccesary lines but I use some of this for multiple projects). Thanks so much!

```
Const olFolderInbox As Integer = 6
Option Compare Text
Sub Filter()
    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application, oOutlook As Object
    Dim oInbox As Outlook.Folder, oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim strAddress As String, strEntryId As String, getSmtpMailAddress As String
    Dim objAddressentry As Outlook.AddressEntry, objExchangeUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser
    Dim objReply As Outlook.MailItem, objRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim oAccount As Outlook.Account
    Dim oOlAp As Object, oOlns As Object, oOlInb As Object
    Dim oOlItm As Object
    Dim Br, Spec As Folder
    Dim oOlAtch As Object
    Dim eSender As String, dtRecvd As String, dtSent As String, o0Acct1 As String, o0Acct2 As String
    Dim sSubj As String, sMsg As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim FName, NewFileName As String
    Dim sn, Subject, F, F2, SF, SF2, SFF, SFF2, From, SJ As String

    'Set objects
'=============================
    Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set oOutlook = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oInbox = oOutlook.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    '~~> Get Outlook instance

    Set myNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")

    i = 0

 For Each Adds In Range("Adds")

    i = i + 1

    MB = Range("MBs")(i)
    F = Range("FromsF")(i)
    F2 = Range("TosF")(i)
    SF = Range("FromsSF")(i)
    SF2 = Range("TosSF")(i)
    SSF = Range("FromsSSF")(i)
    SSF2 = Range("TosSSF")(i)
    From = Range("Adds")(i)
    SJ = Range("Subs")(i)

    With myNS

        For Each Folder In myNS.Folders

            If Folder = MB Then

                If SSF = "" Then

                    Set Br = Folder.Folders(F).Folders(SF)

                Else

                    Set Br = Folder.Folders(F).Folders(SF).Folders(SSF)

                End If

                If SSF2 = "" Then

                    Set ToF = Folder.Folders(F).Folders(SF2)

                    Else

                    Set ToF = Folder.Folders(F).Folders(SF2).Folders(SSF2)

                End If

                For j = Br.Items.Count To 1 Step -1   'loop goes from last to first element
                    ' ----Find Sender's Name
                    If Br.Items(j).SenderEmailType = "SMTP" Then

                        sn = Br.Items(j).SenderEmailAddress

                    Else

                        Set objReply = Br.Items(j).Reply()
                        Set objRecipient = objReply.Recipients.Item(1)

                        strEntryId = objRecipient.EntryID

                        objReply.Close OlInspectorClose.olDiscard

                        strEntryId = objRecipient.EntryID

                        Set objAddressentry = oOutlook.GetAddressEntryFromID(strEntryId)
                        Set objExchangeUser = objAddressentry.GetExchangeUser()

                        On Error Resume Next

                        sn = objExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress()

                    End If
                    '----------------If sender is equal to our address

                    If sn = From Then

                        If SJ <> "" Then
                            SJ = "*" & Range("Subs")(i) & "*"
                            Subject = Br.Items(j).Subject

                            If Subject Like SJ Then

                                Br.Items(j).Move ToF

                            Else
                            End If

                        Else

                            Br.Items(j).Move ToF

                        End If

                    Else
                    End If



                Next j

                Else
                End If

        Next Folder

    End With

Next Adds

End Sub
```

Edit ----------------------------------

So here is my new code.

```
Const olFolderInbox As Integer = 6
Option Compare Text
' FLIRTER WITH DATE FILTERING
Sub FilterTry()
    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application, oOutlook, TargetMail As Object
    Dim oInbox As Outlook.Folder, oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim objAddressentry As Outlook.AddressEntry, objExchangeUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser
    Dim objReply As Outlook.MailItem, objRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim oAccount As Outlook.Account
    Dim oOlAp As Object, oOlItm, oOlAtch, oOlns As Object, oOlInb As Object
    Dim Br, Spec As Folder
    Dim eSender As String, dtRecvd As String, dtSent As String, o0Acct1 As String, o0Acct2 As String
    Dim sSubj As String, sMsg As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim FName, NewFileName As String
    Dim sn, Subject, F, F2, SF, SF2, SFF, SFF2, SJ, From, SJstrAddress As String, strEntryId, getSmtpMailAddress As String
    Dim td, SentDate As Date


    'Set objects
    Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set oOutlook = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oInbox = oOutlook.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)


    '~~> Get Outlook instance
    Set oOlAp = GetObject(, "Outlook.application")
    Set oOlns = oOlAp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oOlInb = oOlns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Br = oOlInb.Folders("Brokers")
    Set Sp = oOlInb.Folders("Confirmation")
    Set Rc = oOlInb.Folders("Recap")
    Set oOlItm = Br.Items
    Set myNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")

    i = 0

    '----Set variables for folders
For Each Adds In Range("Adds")

If Adds <> "" Then
    i = i + 1

    MB = Range("MBs")(i)
    F = Range("FromsF")(i)
    F2 = Range("TosF")(i)
    SF = Range("FromsSF")(i)
    SF2 = Range("TosSF")(i)
    SSF = Range("FromsSSF")(i)
    SSF2 = Range("TosSSF")(i)
    From = Range("Adds")(i)
    SJ = Range("Subs")(i)
    td = Range("Ddate")

    With myNS
        '----- Set To and From Destination folders
        For Each Folder In myNS.Folders

            If Folder = MB Then

                If SSF = "" Then

                    Set Br = Folder.Folders(F).Folders(SF)

                Else

                    Set Br = Folder.Folders(F).Folders(SF).Folders(SSF)

                End If

                If SSF2 = "" Then

                    Set ToF = Folder.Folders(F).Folders(SF2)

                    Else

                    Set ToF = Folder.Folders(F).Folders(SF2).Folders(SSF2)

                End If

                sFilter = "[SenderName] = " & From
                Set Items = Br.Items.Restrict(sFilter)
                msg = Items.Count

                For q = Items.Count To 1 Step -1       'loop goes from last to first element

                    sn = Items(q).SenderEmailAddress
                    SentDt = Items(q).SentOn
                    SentDate = Month(SentDt) & "/" & Day(SentDt) & "/" & Year(SentDt)
                    sn = Items(q).Subject
                    If SentDate >= td Then


                        ' ----Find Sender's Name
                        If Items(q).SenderEmailType = "SMTP" Then

                            sn = Items(q).SenderEmailAddress

                        Else

                            sn = Items(q).PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D01001F")

                            If Len(sn) = 0 Then

                              Set objSender = Items(q).Sender

                              If Not (objSender Is Nothing) Then

                                'read PR_SMTP_ADDRESS_W
                                sn = objSender.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001F")

                                If Len(sn) = 0 Then

                                  'last resort
                                  Set exUser = objSender.GetExchangeUser

                                  If Not (exUser Is Nothing) Then

                                    sn = exUser.PrimarySmtpAddress

                                  End If

                                End If

                              End If

                            End If

                        End If

                        '----------------If sender is equal to our address

                                If SJ <> "" Then

                                    SJ = "*" & Range("Subs")(i) & "*"
                                    Subject = Items(q).Subject

                                    If Subject Like SJ Then

                                        Items(q).Move ToF

                                    Else
                                    End If

                                Else

                                    Items(q).Move ToF

                                End If

                Else
                End If

                Next q

                Else
                End If

        Next Folder

    End With
Else
End If
Next Adds

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Never loop through all items in a folder, use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Res`trict.

Create a restriction on `PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_EMAIL_ADDRESS` (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0065001F`) - that will cover the "SMTP" senders - and on `PidTagSenderSmtpAddress` (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D01001F`) - that will be for the EX senders.

Comment: Great, thanks for the suggestions. I'm out the door now but I'll look into how I can implement these tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried using the  items.restric method. It works almost perfect, but the filter keeps missing certain email addresses. I can type in the exact email, and I know it's searching the correct folders, but the filter shows zero matches. Any idea why it may miss those? I edited in my new code above/.